# Group selection by value of some fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following selection:

```
| EmployeeId | DepartmentName | Salary |
----------------------------------------
| 1          | A              | 10     |
| 2          | A              | 10     |
| 3          | A              | 15     |
| 4          | A              | 20     |
| 5          | A              | 20     |
| 6          | B              | 15     |
| 7          | B              | 25     |
| 8          | B              | 25     |
```

I want to group all rows by salary **in each department** and add this number of group to the selection.

Example of the result selection:

```
| EmployeeId | DepartmentName | Salary | Group |
------------------------------------------------
| 1          | A              | 10     | 1     |
| 2          | A              | 10     | 1     |
| 3          | A              | 15     | 2     |
| 4          | A              | 20     | 3     |
| 5          | A              | 20     | 3     |
| 6          | B              | 15     | 1     |
| 7          | B              | 25     | 2     |
| 8          | B              | 25     | 2     |
```

Comment: Please explain how the `group` is built

Comment: @HappyCoder I try to use DENSE_RANK(), but it groups all rows of selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
      , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentName
                           ORDER BY Salary) AS [Group]
FROM TableName
```